# Check For Type with String in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, types

Say you have an object,

> var obj:Object = someOtherObject;

And you need to check if it is of the type with the name stored in myString

> var myString:String = someOtherString; // ex. "int", "Number", "CustomClass"

I have tried:

> if(obj is getDefinitionByName(myString))

But that doesn't seem to work. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

```
var obj:Object = 5;

var myString:String = "int";

var c:Class = getDefinitionByName(myString) as Class;
if (c && obj is c)
{
    trace("obj is of type "+myString);
}
```

The return type of getDefinitionByName is Object so casting it to Class seems to do the trick.